# Is it okay to send client time zone offset in request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two dates on the client

```
openTime: 2020-01-01 00:00:000 (GMT+2)
closeTime: 2020-01-01 06:00:000 (GMT+2)
```

Before sending it to the server I convert them to ISO

```
openTime.toISOString() // 2019-12-31T22:00:00.000Z
closeTime.toISOString() // 2020-01-01T04:00:00.000Z
```

Server receives these dates and applies validation logic

```js
isSameDay(openTime, closeTime) // false
```

The comparison result is false. It happens because of timezones. Whenever `openTime` with such time converts to UTC the date "jumps" into the different date.

Before converting to ISO
`openTime: 2020-01-01 00:00:000`

After converting to ISO
`openTime: 2019-12-31T22:00:00.000Z`

How to solve this issue?

1. Is it okay to send client `timeZoneOffset` beside `openTime` & `closeTime` values.
2. ..or, send `openTime` & `closeTime` with custom format which adds timezone to the ISO string?

Comment: What concerns you about sending the timezone to the server?

Comment: I'm not sure if my solution is the most suitable for this case. It seems like a general problem and I'm looking for the "best community" solution for this kind of the problem.

Two solutions comes to my mind is "custom format" like `2021-08-02T16:03:26.499+2:00` (+2:00 at the end) and `offsetTimezone: -120` prop inside DTO

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I'd go with your concept of formatting the date with the timezone in it. Make the timezone part `+HH:MM` or `-HH:MM` (four digits) and the JavaScript `Date` object will be able to parse it correctly. (That's part of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) subset that JavaScript supports.) So for instance, `2021-08-02T16:03:26.499+02:00`.

Then, in your server-side, to see whether the open and close are on the same day, you can just use string comparison: `open.substring(0, 10) === close.substring(0, 10)`.

Comment: Why dates comparison should be done by using string literals instead of dates? Any advantages?

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi - Remember that JavaScript dates don't have the concept of a timezone as a piece of their state; they're just an object wrapper around a number representing the number of milliseconds since The Epoch (midnight on Jan 1st 1970 GMT). The only timezone-related feature they have is that you can access the date time either in UTC via the various methods with UTC in their names, or as **local** time (local to the JavaScript environment running the code). So the date you get from `new Date("021-08-02T16:03:26.499+02:00")` has nothing ...

Comment: ... in it that tells you it was originally formatted in `+02:00`; the values you get from the date object are just UTC or local time on your Node.js server. So it saves you some complexity. Thankfully we're getting a better API for working with this soon: [Temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) I wouldn't do anything complex with the strings, but just knowing whether they fall on the same day in their original timezone would be fine.

Comment: I will try your proposal and give you feedback. Thank you a lot for the clarifications.